# How to remove organization from Google Cloud Project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, organization

I am in school, and I accidentally linked my school's org to my Cloud project and now I have limited functionality even though I was the project owner. Is there a way for me to remove them?

Comment: I don't know the answer. It looks like you need Google Support to do this form you. Maybe this article will help: https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-gcp-projects-between-iam-organizations-12c417915bcb

Answer (score 2):

You can't without Google Support's assistance.

> If a project is associated with an organization, you can't change it
>   back to No organization or migrate it to another organization on your
>   own. If you need to migrate a project after it's associated with an
>   organization, you'll need to contact GCP Premium Support.[1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_in_an_organization)

Also of note, you'll likely need approval from the Organizations Administrator as well, this is to prevent projects from being disassociated in 'hostile' type scenarios.

Comment: "disassociated in 'hostile' type scenarios." That seems like a lame slow shortsighted fix. Note, you will need to pay a pretty penny for premium support. This is super lame and should be illegal.